# Pass variables instead using a function

Tags: functions

I've the following code:

```
ProductCost = 10; // product cost
RawCost = 5; // raw material cost
Revenue = ProductCost - RawCost;
Manipulate[Row[{"Product Cost: ", ProductCost,"\n" ,"Product Cost: ", RawCost, "\n", "Revenue: ", Revenue}],{{ProductCost,1},1,20,0.25}, {{RawCost,1},1,20,0.25}]
```

If I run it, Revenue will display a fixed 5 instead of varying under manipulate. Was wondering if there's a way to make it work instead necessarly using functions.

Comment: You do not need the initialization in the first 2 lines, and the line 3 can be put inside `Manipulate`.

Comment: `//` is a [`Postfix`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Postfix.html) operator. If you are trying to enter a comment, use `(* ... *)`, e.g., `ProductCost = 10;  (* product cost *)`

Comment: Variable to be changed in `Manipulate` needs to be **explicit**, this is mentioned in **Possible Issues** section of document of `Manipulate`. If you don't want to use function, consider `With`: `With[{a = ProductCost - RawCost}, 
 Manipulate[Grid[{{"Product Cost: ", ProductCost}, {"Product Cost: ", 
     RawCost}, {"Revenue: ", a}}, Alignment -> Left], {{ProductCost, 1}, 1, 20, 
   0.25}, {{RawCost, 1}, 1, 20, 0.25}]]`

Comment: In your specific case, `Evaluate` the first argument is also a choice. (This method won't work if the first argument cannot be evaluated before receiving values from `Manipulate`): `a = ProductCost - RawCost;

Manipulate[Grid[{{"Product Cost: ", ProductCost}, {"Product Cost: ", 
     RawCost}, {"Revenue: ", a}}, Alignment -> Left] // Evaluate, {{ProductCost, 1}, 
  1, 20, 0.25}, {{RawCost, 1}, 1, 20, 0.25}]`

Comment: @xzczd Thanks, Evaluate is also what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
  Grid[
    {{"Product Cost: ", ProductCost}, 
     {"Product Cost: ", RawCost}, 
     {"Revenue: ", ProductCost - RawCost}}, 
    Alignment -> Left], 
  {{ProductCost, 1}, 1, 20, 0.25}, 
  {{RawCost, 1}, 1, 20, 0.25}]
```